# trying to run a .jar file in command prompt

Tags: java, jar, command-prompt

I am trying to run a jar file using my command prompt (Windows XP) but get NoClassDefFoundError.

I have my DateAndTime.class file in a folder called dateandtime and also indicated a package called dateandtime in the source file.

Outside the folder I have a manifest.mf file with specification

> Main-Class: dateandtime.DateAndTime

I put this in the command file

> jar cmf manifest.mf myJarFile.jar dateandtime

and this creates the myJarFile.jar in the same folder as manifest.mf.

When I try to run this jar file however I get the NoClassDefFoundError

> java -jar myJarFile.jar

If I jave all the classes in the same directory with no package specified then the .jar file runs fine but as soon as I try to specify a package, even though myJarFile.jar was created I get the error.

Why is that?

Regards

Comment: Which class does the `NoClassDefFoundError` indicate is not found? Post the output of `jar tf myJarFile.jar` which will display the contents of your jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` it means a class that was present during compilation of your classes is absent during their execution. Which implies that you JAR file does not contain all the dependencies requires by your classes in order to run. Since your question is lacking detail on your project structure I can only recommend you revisit your application's dependency tree and determine ***all*** the classes that need to be included in the JAR.

Comment: I apologize. I made a mistake with package declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:
java -jar fileName.jar

Example: 
java -jar myfile.jar